# C++ find and erase a multimap element

Tags: c++, indexing, iterator, multimap, erase

I need to add, store and delete some pairs of objects, e.g. `Person`-`Hobby`. Any person can have several hobbies and several persons can have the same hobby. So, multimap is a good container, right?

Before adding a pair I need to know, if it's not added yet. As I can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/) there is no standard class-method to know, if the concrete pair e.g. `Peter-Football` exists in the MM. Thus, I've written a method which returns a positive integer (equal to the distance between mm.begin() and pair iterator) if the pair exists and `-1` otherwise.

Then I need to delete some pair. I call my `find` method, which returns, some positive integer. I call `myMultiMap.erase(pairIndex);` but the pair is not being deleted for some reason. That is my problem. Obviously the `erase` method needs an `iterator`, not the `int`. The question is: how do I convert an integer to an iterator?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I've tried this `c.begin() + int_value` but got an error `error: no match for ‘operator+’` on this line....

Comment: Your custom `find` method presumably uses iterators to figure out if the item exists; just use that iterator, if it is found.

Comment: @tmpearce if my functions would return an iterator, how would I know, if the pair does not exits?

Comment: Wouldn't a `std::set<std::pair<Person, Hobby>>` be a more appropriate container?

Comment: "As I can see here there is no method to know, if the concrete pair e.g. Peter-Football exists in the MM." wrong : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/equal_range/ + iteration from result.first to result.second and checking if it->second==Football

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl obviously I meant the standard method of the class, not the self-written method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I favour your approach, but if the `int` is distance between `begin()` and the iterator in question, you can just use

```
c.begin() + int_value
```

or

```
std::advance(c.begin(), int_value)
```

to get the iterator. The second version is needed for iterators which are not random-access-iterators.

In the interest of your personal sanity (and the program's speed), I'd suggest you return the iterator directly in some form.

There are many possible interfaces that solve this one way or the other. What I would call the "old C way" would be returning by an out parameter:

```
bool find_stuff(stuff, container::iterator* out_iter) {
 ...
 if(found && out_iter)
   *out_iter = found_iter;
 return found;
}
```

use it:

```
container::iterator the_iter;
if(find_stuff(the_stuff, &the_iter)) ...
```

or

```
if(find_stuff(the_stuff, 0)) // if you don't need the iterator
```

This is not idiomatic C++, but Linus would be pleased with it.

The second possible and theoretically sound version is using something like `boost::optional` to return the value. This way, you return either some value or none.

```
boost::optional<container::iterator> find_stuff(stuff) {
 ...
 if(found && out_iter)
   return found_iter;
 return boost::none;
}
```

Use:

```
boost::optional<container::iterator> found = find_stuff(the_stuff);
if(found) {
  do something with *found, which is the iterator.
}
```

or

```
if(find_stuff(the_stuff)) ...
```

Third possible solution would be going the `std::set::insert` way, ie. returning a pair consisting of a flag and a value:

```
std::pair<bool, container::iterator> find_stuff(stuff) {
 ...
 return std::make_pair(found, found_iter);
}
```

Use:

```
std::pair<bool, container::iterator> found = find_stuff(the_stuff);
if(found.first) ...
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `error: no match for ‘operator+’` on line `c.begin() + int_value`.... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kolyunya: your iterator isn't random access.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to change your `mulitmap<Person,Hoobby>` to `set<pair<Person,Hobby> >` - then you will not have problems you have now. Or consider to change to `map<Person, set<Hobby> >`. Both options will not allow to insert duplicate pairs.

Comment: I will need to find all hobbies of a concrete person. Map will allow to do it faster as it stores values sorted, right?

Comment: I updated my response. Second option is `map<Person,set<Hobby>>` - so you will have fast access to Person's hobbies.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 sets(not multi sets) one for hobbies and one for persons, these two acts as filters so you don't add the same person twice(or hobbie). the insert opertations on these sets gives the iterator for the element that is inserted(or the "right" iterator for element if it allready was inserted). The two iterators you get from inserting into hobbies_set and person_set are now used as key and value in a multimap

Using a third set(not multi_set) for the relation instead of a multi_map, may give the advantage of not needing to check before inserting a relation if it is allready there it will not be added again, and if it's not there it will be added. In both ways it will return an iterator and bool(tells if it was allready there or if it was added)

datastructures:

```
typedef std::set<Hobbie> Hobbies;
typedef std::set<Person> Persons;
typedef std::pair<Hobbies::iterator,bool> HobbiesInsertRes;
typedef std::pair<Persons::iterator,bool> PersonsInsertRes;
struct Relation {
  Hobbies::iterator hobbieIter;
  Persons::iterator personIter;
  // needed operator<(left for the as an exercies for the reader);
};
typedef set<Relation> Relations;

Hobbies hobbies;
Persons persons;
Relations relations;
```

insert:

```
HobbiesInsertRes hres = hobbies.insert(Hobbie("foo"));
PersonsInsertRes pres = persons.insert(Person("bar"));
relations.insert(Relation(hres.first, pres.first));
// adds the relation if does not exists, if it allready did exist, well you only paid the same amount of time that you would have if you would to do a check first.
```

lookup:

```
// for a concrete Person-Hobbie lookup use 
relations.find(Relation(Hobbie("foo"),Person("Bar")));

// to find all Hobbies of Person X you will need to do some work.
// the easy way, iterate all elements of relations
std::vector<Hobbie> hobbiesOfX;
Persons::iterator personX = persons.find(Person("bar"));
std::for_each(relations.begin(), relations.end(), [&hobbiesOfBar, personX](Relation r){
  if(r.personIter = personX)
    hobbiesOfX.push_back(r.hobbieIter);
});

// other way to lookup all hobbies of person X
Persons::iterator personX = persons.find(Person("bar"));  
relations.lower_bound(Relation(personX,Hobbies.begin()); 
relations.upper_bound(Relation(personX,Hobbies.end());
// this needs operator< on Relation to be implemented in a way that does ordering on Person first, Hobbie second.
```

Comment: I will then need to find all hobbies of a concrete person. M-Map will allow to do it faster as it stores values sorted, right?

Comment: both maps an sets are sorted only on keys not values